# Recursive function wont return the expected object

Tags: python, recursion

I've written a basic function to recursively look for a `shapely` polygon from the `ox.gdf_from_place` function. Essentially the idea is to call `ox.gdf_from_place` until a polygon is returned. The problem is that my function won't return anything even though it executes fine.

Does anybody have any advice on what to do to get this working?

```
import shapely
import osmnx as ox

result_num = 0

def recursive_find_poly(poi, result_num):

    country = ox.gdf_from_place(poi, which_result=result_num)

    if type(country.unary_union) != shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon:

        result_num += 1

        recursive_find_poly(poi, result_num)
    else:

        return country

test = recursive_find_poly('Istanbul', result_num)
```

Comment: Why did you use recursion? why not simple `for` loop?

Comment: @Guy I'm using recursion as a learning exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `return` statement in the `if` clause:

```
if type(country.unary_union) != shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon:
    result_num += 1
    return recursive_find_poly(poi, result_num)
else:
    return country
```

Otherwise, the value returned by the matching call will get lost.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a recursive function should **always** return something or it shouldn't return anything at all. So I think the problem with your recursive function is: When you are in the *if* block, it does not return anything, but when it is in the *else* block it does return something. If you find a way to rewrite your function so it will **always** return something, I think it will work.